# How to check if extension has cronjobs and start them?

Tags: magento-1, cron

I installed the extension algolia search. But I think its cron job is not running anymore since we moved to another hoster, the term "algolia" is not in the Aoe-Schedueler List.

How can I check if the cronjob of the extension runs and start it if it does not run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type `crontab -l` for list all crons works.
Type `cronteb -e` for add custom crons.

Anyway on Magento Docs is quite good tutorial `how to setup crons`
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

It is possible that u may have to connect to admins for setup crons

Comment: Crons are already set. The result of `crontab -l` is `*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/company/public_html/cron.php` so how do I know if the cron job for algolia is running or not?

Comment: are u using m1 or m2 ?

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9.3

Comment: are u sure that algolia's  cron works before moved to another host ?

Comment: No, im not sure.

Comment: I see. Lets check if module have declared cron. Go to Module /etc/config.xml and look for <crontab><jobs> section

Comment: there is no match for crontab or jobs, so I guess the extension does not have any cronjobs? Wow, I thought it must have a cronjob sorry

Comment: Haha ok. I guess that algoria search a bit different that u think ;) are u looking for way how this module reindex data?

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to rewrite the extension. But I can figure this out by my own. Thx for your introduction into cronjobs in magento :)

Comment: I’m happy to help